# "No route matches" error but rake routes finds it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

Alright, getting a pretty bizarre routing error here.

```
No route matches {:controller=>"subscriptions", :action=>"change"}

Extracted source (around line #22):

19:     <td><%= s.product.name %></td>
20:     <td><%= s.calc_time_to_next_arrival %></td>
21:     <td>
22:         <%= form_for(:subscription, s, :url => { :action => "change" }, :id => s) do %>
23:             <%= label_tag(:q, "Days to delay:") %>
24:             <%= text_field_tag(:query) %>
25:             <%= check_box_tag(:always) %>
```

And yet if I run rake routes this is what I get

```
change_subscription GET    /subscriptions/:id/change(.:format {:controller=>"subscriptions", :action=>"change"}
```

Pretty sure that means it should be there. Not sure what is going on.

Here is where the route is stated in routes.rb

```
resources :subscriptions do
    member do
      get 'change'
    end
  end
```

Here's the controller though for subscriptions

```
def change
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
    @subscription.change(:query, :always)
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>That should be `post 'change'`, instead of `get 'change'`</strike>

Er, I meant `put 'change'`, of course.

How about:

`<%= form_for s, :url => change_subscription_path(s) do |f| %>`

Comment: Already tried that. Tried it again, and restarted the server for good measure. Output of rake routes is updated properly, still get this error. (Likewise, tried "put" just for giggles)